# How to make fade transition when I leave a scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have `LevelManager` and `LevelManager.cs` and it's not a `singleton`.
I wanna make fade transition between scenes. I made animations for `Fade_In` and  `Fade_Out`. And for the first it works fine but when I'd like to leave a scene, it (`Fade_Out`) doesn't work.

Some of `LevelManager.cs`:

```
private void Start() {
    if (autoLoadNextLevelAfter != 0) {
        Invoke("FadeOut", autoLoadNextLevelAfter);
    }
}

public void LoadLevel(string name) {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
}

public void LoadNextLevel() {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
}

private void FadeOut() {
    animator.SetTrigger("FadeOut");
}
```

In the `Start` method I call `Invoke` of animation and at the end of `Fade_Out` I call `LoadNextLevel` method. In this case, `Fade_Out` works fine.
But If I wanna make transition with `LoadLevel` (it calls when I push the button) it breaks. I tried to make `IEnumerator LoadLevel`:

```
public void NewLoadLevel(string name) {
    FadeOut();
    StartCoroutine(CoroutLoadLevel(name));
}

private IEnumerator CoroutLoadLevel(string name) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
}
```

The console says: `Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object 'LevelManager' is inactive!`. I guess it's because `LevelManager` is not a `singleton`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the LevelManager is active and enabled. A coroutine needs an active object to run (because if it is not active update logic will not be called).

Comment: I read about this error recently it's because I use a prefab of `LevelManager`. And of course my object is active, lol. I think about making a `singleton` of `LevelManager` but I don't know how to realise it in my project.